# how to backup data in mysql for a specific date and time?

Tags: mysql, database

I want to set up an event to back up my database at midnight every Friday night. I know how to do it for a given time like every hour.

Here is the code I have

```
    CREATE EVENT 'BackUp'
    on schedule every 12 Friday 
    comment 'Update database'
    do
delete from baseball.seasons;

show events;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Friday midnight is the same as Saturday at 00:00:

```
ON SCHEDULE
  EVERY 1 WEEK
  STARTS CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 5 - WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE) DAY
```